# Color from cards are not changing after event is fired

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

So I've a problem where I want to change colors from my cards everytime a customer get subscribed to a gym class. ( Red for already subscribed, yellow when is open to subscription)

The problem I'm getting is, anytime when I make a subscription to one class, all the elements from the array, got the color red, instead of one.

[image]

So I've an array of classes(named **fechaClases**) which looks like this:

[image: classes]

My **HTML** code looks like this:

```
 <ion-card color="light" *ngFor="let fecha of fechaCards">
        <ion-item color="warning">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="fitness"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>
                <h2 style="font-weight: bold">{{ fecha | date:'d/MMMM/yyyy' | uppercase }}</h2>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- CONTENIDO --> ---> **Here is where I want to change colors** 
        <ion-card-content>  
            <ng-container *ngFor="let clase of fechaClases">
                <ion-item [color]="getColor()" (click)="inscripcion(clase)" *ngIf="clase.horaCierre == fecha">
                    <h2 slot="start" style="font-weight: bold">{{ clase.horaApertura | date: 'shortTime' }}</h2>
                    <h2 slot="end">{{ "Cupos disponibles" + " " + clase.cuposDisponibles + "/" + clase.cupos }}</h2>
                </ion-item>
            </ng-container>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

**getColor()**

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.fechaClases.length; index++) {
      if (this.fechaClases[index].estaInscripto == true) {

        console.log(this.fechaClases[index].estaInscripto, 'true');
        return 'danger'
      }
      else {
        return 'warning'
      }
    }
```

what i'm doing wrong? Hope anyone can help me :) Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think in a more "angular" way.

Your list is created by iterating over your *fechaClases* array, using the *ngFor directive. You just need a conditional binding of the *color* property, checking the *estaInscripto* property of each array object.

So, change this line:

```
<ion-item [color]="getColor()" (click)="inscripcion(clase)" *ngIf="clase.horaCierre == fecha">
```

with this one:

```
<ion-item [color]="clase.estaInscripto? 'danger' : 'warning'" (click)="inscripcion(clase)" *ngIf="clase.horaCierre == fecha">
```

Also, delete your *getColor()* function, there is no need for it.

Check this stackblitz (inside the *home* page *.html* and *.ts* files) with simplified, working example of the above.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-e7pfdz